# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "STOCK" Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, exception, jdbc

I get an error like this, but I don't have a column named "Stock".

That is an Error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.hilmi.AutomotiveECommerceApplication.main(AutomotiveECommerceApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [NULL not allowed for column "STOCK"; SQL statement:
insert into products (brand_id,category_id,created_date,description,name,price,quantity,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default) [23502-214]] [insert into products (brand_id,category_id,created_date,description,name,price,quantity,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default)]; SQL [insert into products (brand_id,category_id,created_date,description,name,price,quantity,updated_date,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,default)]; constraint [null]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:269) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy153.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.hilmi.bootstrap.BootstrapData.run(BootstrapData.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
```

You can see that there is not a Stock Column in the Product.java
Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product extends BaseEntity {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<ShoppingCardItem> shoppingCardItems;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<OrderItem> orderItems;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
    private Brand brand;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Image> images;
}
```

Bootstrap.java

```
@Component
public class BootstrapData implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final BrandRepository brandRepository;
    private final ImageRepository imageRepository;
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CityRepository cityRepository;
    private final DistrictRepository districtRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public BootstrapData(CategoryRepository categoryRepository, ProductRepository productRepository,
                         CountryRepository countryRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository,
                         BrandRepository brandRepository, ImageRepository imageRepository,
                         CustomerRepository customerRepository, CityRepository cityRepository,
                         DistrictRepository districtRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.brandRepository = brandRepository;
        this.imageRepository = imageRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.cityRepository = cityRepository;
        this.districtRepository = districtRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        roleRepository.save(new Role(0, ERole.ROLE_USER));
        roleRepository.save(new Role(0, ERole.ROLE_ADMIN));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<Category> categories = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/categories.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<Category>>() {
                });

        List<Product> products = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/products.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {
                });

        List<Brand> brands = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/brands.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<Brand>>() {
                });

        List<Image> images = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/images.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<Image>>() {
                });

        List<Country> countries = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/countries.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<Country>>() {
                });

        List<City> cities = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/cities.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<City>>() {
                });

        List<District> districts = objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/districts.json"),
                new TypeReference<List<District>>() {
                });

        categoryRepository.saveAll(categories);
        brandRepository.saveAll(brands);
        productRepository.saveAll(products);
        imageRepository.saveAll(images);
        countryRepository.saveAll(countries);
        cityRepository.saveAll(cities);
        districtRepository.saveAll(districts);

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN).get());
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("H");
        customer.setLastName("B");
        customer.setEmail("h@gmail.com");
        customer.setUsername("hbas");
        customer.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"));
        customer.setEmailVerified(true);
        customer.setRoles(roles);
        customerRepository.save(customer);

        List<Role> roles1 = new ArrayList<>();
        roles1.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER).get());
        Customer customer1 = new Customer();
        customer1.setFirstName("Ah");
        customer1.setLastName("Tu");
        customer1.setEmail("ahtu@gmail.com");
        customer1.setUsername("aTurk");
        customer1.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"));
        customer1.setEmailVerified(true);
        customer1.setRoles(roles1);
        customerRepository.save(customer1);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AutomotiveECommerceApplication {

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AutomotiveECommerceApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

My Data
products.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bosch Brake",
    "description": "Description",
    "price": 799.99,
    "quantity": 20,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Engine"
    },
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bosch"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bosch Fuel Pump",
    "description": "Description",
    "price": 150.00,
    "quantity": 30,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Engine"
    },
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bosch"
    }
  }
]
```

Why am I getting such an error even though I don't have a column named "**Stock**"?

Comment: There is a column in the DB schema (which you haven't shown) named "Stock".